# Graphing services using pnp4nagios

Tags: nagios

I've managed to install pnp4nagios 0.6.3 and I'm a bit confused about how pnp4nagios generates graphics.
  Almost out of the box, it started graphs for ping and some http servers (not all of them). But, how can I make it graph things like disk utilization (When that value comes from SNMP)??

For example,

```
ls /usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/isis/

Cola_de_Mail.rrd  Cola_de_Mail.xml  HTTP.rrd  HTTP.xml  PING.rrd  PING.xml
```

Those are checks running on the host isis, but there are many other checks for that server that are not taken into account by pnp4nagios. How can I make pnp4nagios "see" the other checks??

Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Reading a bit more, it seems the problem might be because the checking script is not writing Performance Data :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my nagios commands weren't supporting Performance data. A nagios command for support performance data must have an output similar to this:

```
status_information|performance_data
```

If the command doesn't support performance data, you can write a wrapper for that command. Automagically the XML files are created and the services appear in the web interface! :-)

Links:
http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/wrapper
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/1_0/perfdata.html

Answer (score 0):

Nagios dont plot this graphs.

rrd do that.

man rrdtool

and check what in you rrd files (is data collected right?)